# Android Retrofit adding shared preference value in end point

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, retrofit, retrofit2

I am new in using retrofit in android. I have a get request which is working in a good manner but I want to include the value of shared preference in the endpoint of the URL. Suppose my end point Url is :

```
public interface Data{
    @GET("/myphone/extra/pull/Sharedpreferencevalue") //add shared preference value here
}
```

Can I do this in retrofit or I have to do with some other way? or how it can be done in retrofit?

Comment: check query parameters @ http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add parameters dynamically as follows:

```
@GET("/myphone/extra/pull/{Sharedpreferencevalue}")
Call<YourResponseClass> getData(@Path("Sharedpreferencevalue") String value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Path` annotation to programmatically add value to the endpoint, and do something like this in your with retrofit Service interface:

```
@GET("/myphone/extra/pull/{sharedprefValue}")
Call<EntityName> getPref(@Path("sharedprefValue") String pref);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use urls dynamically to retrofit2 as follows.

in your interface

```
 @GET
public Call<ResponseBody> fetchMileage(@Url String url);
```

use it this way

```
OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(ROOT_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
    Retrofit retrofit =  builder.client( httpClient.build()).build();
    MyInterface myInterface = retrofit.create(MyInterface.class);
    Call<ResponseBody> result = myInterface.fetchMileage(endpointUrl);
    result.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            String output ="";
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                try {

                    output = response.body().string();


                }catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }else{
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable throwable) {
            //Toast.makeText(context,"Error "+throwable.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            throwable.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```